# Date formatter returns null

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

I am always getting a null from the date formatter. I tried examples in all the other questions and didn't help.

```
 NSLog(@"Date is %@", summaryItem.SubmittedDate);
NSLog(@"Formatted Date is %@", [df stringFromDate: summaryItem.SubmittedDate ]);
BOOL isDate = [summaryItem.SubmittedDate isKindOfClass: [NSDate class]];
NSLog(@"Date %@ a date.", isDate ? @"is" : @"is not");
```

Looking at the definition of SubmittedDate you have

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *SubmittedDate;
```

I am initializing the Date Fomatter as so

```
- (void) initDateFormatter {
  if( df == nil ) {
    df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    [df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
  }
}
```

1. Output to Log:

   - 2012-11-21 10:00:41.650 Mobile_v2[4093:f803] Date is 11/21/2012 10:00:41 AM
   - 2012-11-21 10:00:41.651 Mobile_v2[4093:f803] Formatted Date is (null)
   - 2012-11-21 10:00:41.681 Mobile_v2[4093:f803] Date is not a date.

Can anyone see what's wrong? Is my date format incorrect?

Code in my SBJson class

```
NSString *newDate = (NSString *)[receivedObjects objectForKey:@"SubmittedDate"];
NSDate *submittedDate = [df dateFromString:newDate];  //(NSDate *) 
if ((NSNull *) submittedDate == [NSNull null]) {
    self.SubmittedDate = nil;
} else {
    self.SubmittedDate = submittedDate;
}
```

Actual value is "11/21/2012 10:47:54 AM"

Comment: `setDateFormat` and `setDateStyle` are mutually exclusive. `setDateStyle` will effectively set a built-in date format.

Comment: You also need to set a locale.

Comment: I am translating this value "11/21/2012 10:47:54 AM" and NSDate becomes nil. But if I use the string "11/21/2012" NSDate is valid. How can I create an NSDate and keep the time component? I added the json code into the question for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your log   **summaryItem.SubmittedDate** object is not of class NSDate.

First log the class of that object,

```
NSLog(@"%@",  [summaryItem.SubmittedDate class]);
```

if the output is not NSDate, there is something wrong in implementation (.m file) in the class where 
`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *SubmittedDate;` is declared.

Comment: I think you mean NSLog(@"%@", [summaryItem.SubmittedDate class]); ?

Comment: See my comment above. The issue appears to be that if I have a time component in the string it fails.

Comment: That might be because you have set:  [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you using NSDateFormatter to convert from string to date when parsing JSON respnose bacause:

1. You have to set proper date format [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"].
2. NSDateFormatter is very slow.

Instead use UNIX time stamp (no of seconds from 1-1-1970) and,

```
-(id)initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
```

to create the date object.